# difference in two strings by substring search

Tags: notepad++, search

Do you think it is possible with notepad++ to do difference of two strings on a substring level??

Check if any element from list1 exists in list2. If so remove it. At the end return only those unique

```
list1    - "a" "b" "a" "a" "c" "f" "g"
list2    - "a" "c" "a" "f"
-------------------
result   - "b" "g"
```

list1 and list2 could be two separate files or just two separate lines. Elements could be comma separated or just whitespace/spacebar separated

Would be cool to know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a stepwise approach for it:

1. remove repetitions within lines:

   - look for `(.*)("[a-z]*")(.*)\2(.*)`
   - replace to `\1\3\4`
   - presss "replace all" (you may need to repeat it multiple times in order to remove all)
2. remove substrings found in both lines:

   - look for `(.*)("[a-z]*")(.*)\r\n(.*)\2(.*)`
   - replace to `\1\3\r\n\4\5`
   - presss "replace all" (again: you may need to repeat it multiple times in order to remove all)

This works if items within lines are surrounded by `"` characters and contains only small letters, you probably will need to modify it for your needs.

Comment: Hi Mate. Many thanks. I did some tests with no luck. Could you elaborate a bit more ? Sorry if my question sounds stupid but  (.*)("[a-z]*")(.*)\2(.*)  selects whole line

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's not a problem if it selects the whole line, let's see what will delete and what will keep.